# Displaying data from another two different tables on an index page

Tags: html, mysql, ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm struggling to get data from two separate tables to display on the same index page.

I have data from one table displaying as a list this table is called "transactions".

Now in my model for transactions I have defined that it has many "notes. which is my other table I want to display data from on this same index.

I want each transaction to display the notes associated with it by the id of the transaction and the id in the notes table under transaction_id.

For the life of me I have yet to figure out how to do this.

Here is what my transactions index.html.erb looks like:

```
<% @transactions.each do |transaction| %>
<div class="element">
  <%= trash_ico(transaction) %>
  <%= edit_ico(transaction, edit_transaction_path(transaction)) %>
  <%= link_to "<h2><span class=\"el_header\">#{Asset.find(transaction.asset_id).nmc_name} : Assigned to #{User.find(transaction.user_id).name}</span></h2>
    <div class=\"el\">Created: #{transaction.created_at}</div>
    <div class=\"el\">Ended: #{transaction.finished}</div>
    <div class=\"el\">Type: #{if ! transaction.transaction_type.nil? then transaction.transaction_type.name end}</div>
    <div class=\"el\">Status: #{if ! transaction.transaction_status.nil? then transaction.transaction_status.name end}</div>
    <br clear=\"all\" />".html_safe, transaction %>

  <% note.each do |note| %>
    <%= link_to "<div>#{note.notes}</div>".html_safe, note %>

  <% end %>

</div>
<% end %>
```

And this is how the controller is defined for the index:

```
def index
  unless params[:asset_id].nil?
    @transactions = Transaction.find_all_by_asset_id(params[:asset_id])
  else
    @transactions = Transaction.all 
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @transactions }
  end
end
```

I'm very green to programming but mostly to rails. I see what the task is that I need to do, but I'm not sure what the syntax must be to do it.

I have a similar view setup for my show def. I just can't get notes to show underneath their respective transaction on the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking, something like this;

```
<% transaction.notes.each do |note| %>
    <%= link_to "<div>#{note.notes}</div>".html_safe, note %>
<% end %>
```

Since you declared notes belonging to transactions. Rails allows you to access them this way.

Comment: `<div>#{note.notes}</div>` should probably be `<div>#{note.content}</div>` or `<div>#{note.title}</div>` or something

Comment: hmmmm, I tried adding transaction to my each do, but it threw a :

undefined method `note' for #<Transaction:0x007f45ca02ce90>

@Benjamin the reason I'm calling note.notes is that in the database table for notes. the column I want is called notes. which stores text when a note is created. so I want to display that text for each note that is associated with each transaction. if that makes sense.

I'm just not sure how it is that I should be calling that column to be displayed on the transactions index.

Comment: I've tried defining it as @notes.find(transaction.id).transaction_id, or Note.find(transaction.id).transaction_id, or @transactions.find(note.transaction_id).id. 

I'm not sure what it is that I'm looking for or what terminology that I should use to find more information on this particular issue.

I'm looking through http://www.railstutorial.org/ to see if I can find something related to this. I'm just missing it.

Comment: Just saw that I had a typo in my change based on user2963716's suggestion. had transaction.note.each do instead of transaction.notes.each do.

I'm watching the console as it queries the database, and its selecting notes based on id of the transaction.

I'm so glad this seems to be working I'll update once it loads. there are some 18,000 transactions.

....I need to get pagination working...

Comment: That did the trick! Though now, I want to understand why that worked.

Would you mind pointing me to some resources that discuss this area of rails? I want to understand what it is I'm doing when writing these methods since this is the heart of what rails is for.

Thanks again!